# RobotFramework : How to retrieve the row of an array corresponding to a cell value

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

In the UI I'm working with, for an object there there is a pencil or a basket icon; I want to click the pencil one (which will trigger an edit modal), and want to do it for the specific object.

For now I use this command line:

```
Click Element xpath = (//a[@ng-click="openCreateEditModal (holding)"])[2]
```

I would like to replace the "2" by the value of the line corresponding to the value "RF-Account".

Here is a sample of the HTML:

```
<tbody ng-if="!isEmpty" class="body-table ng-scope" style="height: 165px;">
        <!-- ngRepeat: tenant in tenants track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="tenant in tenants track by $index" class="ng-scope" style="">
            <td class="ng-binding">RF-Accou</td>
            <td>
                <span class="text-bold ng-binding text-muted" ng-class="{'text-green' : tenant.status == 'ACTIVE', 'text-muted' : tenant.status == 'INACTIVE'}">INACTIVE</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:118px">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a name="editBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-edit fs" data-toggle="tooltip" title=""></span>
                    </a>
                    <a name="deleteBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="deleteTenant(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-trash fs" data-toggle="tooltip" title=""></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in tenants track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="tenant in tenants track by $index" class="ng-scope">
            **<td class="ng-binding">RF-Account</td>**
            <td>
                <span class="text-bold ng-binding text-muted" ng-class="{'text-green' : tenant.status == 'ACTIVE', 'text-muted' : tenant.status == 'INACTIVE'}">INACTIVE</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:118px">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a name="editBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-edit fs" data-toggle="tooltip" title=""></span>
                    </a>
                    <a name="deleteBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="deleteTenant(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-trash fs" data-toggle="tooltip" title=""></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in tenants track by $index --><tr ng-repeat="tenant in tenants track by $index" class="ng-scope">
            <td class="ng-binding">RF-Accountfirst</td>
            <td>
                <span class="text-bold ng-binding text-muted" ng-class="{'text-green' : tenant.status == 'ACTIVE', 'text-muted' : tenant.status == 'INACTIVE'}">INACTIVE</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width:118px">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <a name="editBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-edit fs" data-toggle="tooltip" title=""></span>
                    </a>
                    <a name="deleteBtn" type="submit" class="btn-icon" ng-click="deleteTenant(tenant)">
                        <span class="icon-i-trash fs" data-toggle="tooltip" title=""></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in tenants track by $index -->
    </tbody>
```

I am trying to find the line that corresponds to the text value "RF-Account".
For your information, the line of "RF-Account" can change.

Could you please help me find the right keyword to use for Robot Framework ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: On this same line I would like to click on a pencil or a basket.
For now I use this command line: Click Element xpath = (// a [@ ng-click = "openCreateEditModal (holding)"]) [2].
I would like to replace the "2" by the value of the line corresponding to the value "RF-Account"

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase your question - you need a locator that'll get you that, not a robotframework keyword (the keyword is known, `Click Element`).

If your anchor is the text, then this xpath will do it for you:

```
//td[text()="RF-Account"]/following-sibling::td//a[@ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)"]
```

Let me explain: the first part (`//td[text()="RF-Account"]`) will select a `td` element which text is "RF-Account". Then it will look for a follow-up `td` (the "following-sibling axis), that has an `a` child with that value for ng-click - and return it (the `a`).

BTW, in the sample source there is no "openCreateEditModal(holding)", thus I've changed it with "tenant", which is present.

Comment: You can simplify this locator to `//td[.="RF-Account"]/following-a[@ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)"]`.

Comment: @JeffC as given `following-a` will be treated as a node name (which obviously won't match anything). If your intent was to write `following::a` - then this would change the locator's purpose - it would be catching all `a` nodes with that attribute after the matched `td` - OP's aim is to catch a single one. An I missing something here?

Comment: Yep... you are right, that's a typo that should have been `::`. When you use `.findElement()`, it only returns the first found element so the rest are ignored.

Comment: Many thanks to you both for your help. it works perfectly. I learned a new element of RF it will certainly make you laugh but I was going to browse the table to look for the number of the line containing "RF-Account".

Answer (score 0):

For getting count you can use

Get Matching XPath Count  //td[.="RF-Account"]